# Making SQlite3 inserts faster using Perl API

Tags: perl, sqlite

I am DBD::SQLite to insert some data in SQlite3 db using perl.

I have noticed that it takes a lot of time to insert(inserting 35k rows).
Is there any way to make it faster.

Optimization is important for me rather than data sync.
How can i optimize it using perl?

Please help.

Comment: Are you doing single row inserts or batch inserts?

Comment: currently doing single row inserts.

Comment: Is Perl an API? What do you mean?

Comment: @Zaid Perl would be the programming language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try executing this statement before doing your inserts:

```
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF
```

See the SQLite documentation for [more information](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous).

Also, as Ilion notes, try to `prepare()` the statement just once and then re-`execute()` multiple times with different bind values.  Turning off `AutoCommit` and then explicitly committing only every N rows inserted may also help, for some values of N.

Comment: also with a new-enough SQLite, `PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL` (or even `= OFF` if you really don't care about data integrity)

Comment: And except for the `PRAGMA` trick, all of this same advice usually works for speeding up inserts into any relational database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are using prepared statements so it doesn't have to analyze each insert. Also try grouping your insert statements by surrounding them with Begin ... Commit [as described in this FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `AutoCommit => 0` set on your connection.
Insteed, commit explicitly after every batch of inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Beside turning auto-commit off altogether, you can also try using a large transaction. Makes all the difference to single-row inserts, usually.